# Data Binding to docitem within repeat control (get and set !)

Tags: data-binding, xpages

I've tried to build EL expression out of strings within the repeat control.

```
...
<xp:this.value>
     <![CDATA[#{javascript:
         return '#{docVG.Feat' + lnr + '}';
      }]]>
</xp:this.value>
...
```

But that fails. I found this:

[Dynamic binding within a repeat control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155563/dynamic-binding-within-a-repeat-control)

That gave me a good understanding. But it deals only with read items.
Is it possible to achieve read and write with this approach ?

My complete repeat looks like this. It builds a huge amount of checkBoxes (in postsave i will put them together in one item). The cause is bad rendering of xp:checkboxgroup (in tables...).

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" value="#{viewFPbx1}" repeatControls="false" var="col" indexVar="lnr" disableOutputTag="true">
    <xp:checkBox uncheckedValue="">
        <xp:this.text>
             <![CDATA[#{javascript:
             col.getColumnValue("Subject");
             }]]>
         </xp:this.text>
        <xp:this.value>
             <![CDATA[#{javascript:
             return '#{docVG.Feat' + lnr + '}';
             }]]>
         </xp:this.value>
        <xp:this.checkedValue>
             <![CDATA[#{javascript:
             col.getColumnValue("Alias");
             }]]>
         </xp:this.checkedValue>
         <xp:this.defaultChecked>
             <![CDATA[#{javascript:
             col.getColumnValue("initial");                                   
             }]]>
         </xp:this.defaultChecked>
    </xp:checkBox>
    </li>
</xp:repeat>
```

Comment: If you are not happy with the rendered output of xp:checkboxgroup, why not create your own renderer?

Comment: You're not using EL, your are using SSJS. Try *value="#{docVG.Feat' + lnr + '}"* instead.

Comment: value="#{docVG.Feat' + lnr + '}" does not work !!  Syntax Error in IDE

Comment: You may also need repeatControls="true". I believe data bindings need to be available on page load, not recalculated during the lifecycle.

Comment: @Sven: I don't know how to create my own renderer ?? Do you have any links with hints  for realizing that  ??

Comment: Here's an example of one for removing table tags from a Radio Button Group https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=remove-table-tag-for-radiogroups-in-read-mode-for-all-instances

Answer (score 2):

Probably an easier approach will be to extract the information you need from the document into an ArrayList or Map stored in viewScope in beforePageLoad, then bind to that. In your save, write the viewScope back to the document.

If you're using a Save Document simple action or a button of type Submit, change it. Unless you've got a simple form, don't rely on Simple Actions. You should already be capable of using SSJS `document1.save()` (if `document1` is your datasource name) before trying to achieve complex binding like this.

Comment: Sounds good. I'm able to create the Arraylist on Pageload and write it back later. But i don't understand how changes of the checkBoxes are walking back to the ArrayList. How does the value of each ckeckBox is looking within the repeatControl ?

Comment: With a field, the name is myField0, myField1 etc. With an ArrayList, you bind to an index of the ArrayList, so myField[0]. So binding to that via EL is along the lines of Tim Tripcony's answer to the other question.